# Interview phase for SMC immigration - NZ

Tags: immigration, new-zealand

> Please let me know a few times and days when you might be free during London business hours and your preferred land line phone number. If you cannot provide a landline number, I can call a mobile phone, but we will only proceed with the interview if the call quality is good enough. I will confirm the interview time with you by email.

I received above email on *Tuesday,11-Aug-2015*, from an immigration officer asking for,

> 1) times and days for availability of formal interview, under **skilled migrant category** without employment offer.
>
> 2) Full blood count report of my partner.

I have replied next day(Wednesday), about my availability on 13-aug and 14-aug from 14:30hrs to 16:00 hrs.

I have also replied(on Thursday) with a medical report, as requested.
But am yet to receive a reply from immigration officer.

Shall I call the customer care?

Is there something to worry?

How do I proceed in this regard?

Comment: Did the email say that an interview the same week was possible? My guess is that the days you gave were too soon and the officer may have been scheduling two or three weeks in advance. But that's only a guess.